# Build a file with large string

Tags: linux, string, unix, text, large-files

We need to build a large text file around 1MB in size. We tried with shell script using Echo to create file using do loop. It took a long time to build.

I am looking to build a file 1 line/record in unix/Linux. It could be a large string of size 1MB.

The content may look like this, but for a whole megabyte:

```
XXXXXXXXX............................................XXXX
```

If I build character by character, it takes longer time.

I would like to extend this to 10MB, 20MB .... 60MB later on.

Is a shell script the best option, or is there a faster option?

Comment: Making a small program (in a compiled language like C or Ocaml) writing such a file is faster than asking the question on a forum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The unix `dd` command was made exactly for this purpose.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29

You could write a small program to continuously print your desired fill character (`X` in your example) to STDOUT without newlines. Pipe the result of that into `dd` and specify the `bs` and `count` parameters such that you get the exactly correct file size.

You can then tweak the `bs` and `count` parameters to find the maximum throughput.

EDIT: Example:

```
yes X | awk '{ printf("%s", $0)}' | dd of=out.txt bs=1024 count=1024 2>/dev/null
```

You can see that it's quite fast:

```
time yes X | awk '{ printf("%s", $0)}' | dd of=out.txt bs=1024 count=1024 
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.123118 s, 8.5 MB/s

real    0m0.127s
user    0m0.144s
sys         0m0.004s
```

Moving the `time` through the different parts of the pipeline indicates to me that `dd` is taking whatever you give it, but the producer is not very fast. (Perhaps `yes` and `awk` aren't the best combination).

If you need to go faster than that, perhaps you'll need to consider other interfaces, for example `mmap`.

Comment: That small program exists. Use `yes(1)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply/comments. Do you have a sample code of your suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Specify number of bytes -- in this example, 1024

```
printf 'B%.0s' {1..1024} > test; du -b test
    1024    test
```

Specify number of kibibytes (binary kilobytes) -- in this example, 76

```
K=`printf 'B%.0s' {1..1024}`; printf "$K"'%.0s' {1..76} > test; ls -sh test
    76K test
```

Specify number of mebibytes (binary megabytes) -- in this example, 45

```
K=`printf 'B%.0s' {1..1024}`; M=`printf "$K"'%.0s' {1..1024}`; printf "$M"'%.0s' {1..45} > test; ls -sh test
    45M test
```

Specify number of kilobits for networking -- in this example, 2

```
kbit=`printf 'B%.0s' {1..125}`; printf "$kbit"'%.0s' {1..2} > test; cat test; echo

    BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
    BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
    BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
    BBBBBBBBBB
```

Specify number of megabits for networking -- in this example, 2

```
kbit=`printf 'B%.0s' {1..125}`; mbit=`printf "$kbit"'%.0s' {1..1000}`; printf "$mbit"'%.0s' {1..2} > test
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use "dd" command

see example below

dd if=/dev/zero of=LARGE_FILE bs=1M count=10000

Comment: That builds a large zero-filled file, not a large textual file.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any alternate to dd?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `/dev/zero`, `tr` and `head`:

This will produce a 1MB file with A:s:

```sh
cat /dev/zero | tr '\0' A | head -c 1000000 > A.txt
```